# Does this sentence sound strange to your ears? - "Not anyone can be a poet."

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, meaning-in-context

Thank you so much for checking out my question!

I am currently trying to be a teacher of English in Japan and reviewing the basic grammars
of English.
And I hit a wall. I cannot explain what is wrong with the sentence as follows:

> "Not anyone can be a poet."

I usually write "Not everyone can be a poet." to express the same meaning.
However, even though something seems to be very wrong with the sentence above, I am unable to nail down what is actually wrong...

Can someone please kindly enlighten me with this issue in terms of grammar and usage?

Thank you so much for your time!!

Comment: _Not just anyone can be a poet_ is idiomatic, but it does sound odd without the _just_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion “not everyone can be a poet” is a general way of saying. “Not anyone can be a poet” can be used when subjects are talked about or are in front of you, students for instance, who’ve discussed their desire or wish to become poets.

Comment: I understood what you meant and it seems to be like a connotation-level issue. So it should theoretically grammatically correct but less often used.

Answer (score 2):

You can say in the affirmative "Anyone can be a poet", but the literal meaning of "not anyone" is "no-one". Using "not everyone" instead makes the meaning much clearer.

Comment: Thank your your answer! It seems even though we cannot say "it's wrong!", somewhat is is not best way to describe what is meant to say!  Thank you!